# Why does ICollection not contain an Add method?

Tags: c#, .net, api-design

As in the title, does anyone know why the `ICollection` interface does not contain an Add method? It seems very odd that the generic version, `ICollection<T>`, has an `Add` but `ICollection` does not. Anyone with deeper knowledge on this would be really helpful.

As to why I care- unfortunately the developers who build SharePoint have never learned about generics, so every single collection in the API is a a non-generic collection based off of `ICollection`. I'd like to attach several extension methods to `ICollection` that involve adding to the collection, among other things, but this seems to be impossible (at least not possible without reflection).

EDIT:

Quite a few people are *speculating* the reason is because `ICollection.Add` would require an `Object`, and thus wouldn't be typesafe. This isn't the case. `IList` *has* an `Add` method that takes an `Object`. You simply need to do a typecheck and a cast in a method that takes `Object`.

The argument that an array implements `ICollection` and therefore it can't have an `Add` also doesn't hold water. If `ICollection` had an `Add` method, it would just need to be explicitly implemented on arrays and throw an Exception (as many of the methods arrays implement currently do).

I was really hoping someone had a reference to an explanation by one of the designers.

Comment: it does ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx

Comment: @MicahArmantrout, he says `ICollection<T>` does, but `ICollection` does not.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout You linked to the generic version. He already said the generic version has it. He is asking why the [non-generic one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps it's because an `Add` in `ICollection` would have to take `object`, but it doesn't make sense to define `Add(object)` in, e.g. `List<int>`. (you can't add any object to a `List<int>`)  However, `IList` has `Add(object)`, so this argument doesn't hold up too well.  The reasons are probably historical: that's the way it was first made, and it was never considered worth making that breaking change.

Comment: What IList did is independent of ICollection--that assumes some level of perfection and consistency between IList and ICollection.  You can't assume that.

Comment: Why does it matter?  `ICollection` isn't going to change, it currently doesn't have an `Add` method.  Knowing *why* doesn't add any value.  the only *real* answer is *no one implemented an Add method*.  There may really be no deeper reason.  Anything else is really just speculation--which doesn't give you much value.

Comment: @MgSam the god of C# Anders Hejlsberg is not on stackoverflow..:(

Comment: @PeterRitchie Then why come on this website at all? The entire point is to ask and answer questions about programming and development. For a central base class library, there is obviously a reason why other than "no one bothered to do it".

Comment: @Anirudha No, but a lot of other MS employees visit this site though, including .NET and C# developers.

Comment: @mgsam There are questions that have authoritative answers and questions that have useful answers (and a combination of the two)--that's why people come to this site.  What is the *value* to to you knowing *why* there isn't an `ICollection.Add` method if someone *could* answer it authoritatively?

Comment: @PeterRitchie a) It's interesting to know *why* things are the way they are. b) In my case, the lack of an `Add` is causing an actual issue in **current** MS products. Asking questions is another way for MS to get feedback on these things. Your reasoning is very odd. Why should you, personally, care that the universe is made of atoms or that you digest food in your small intestine? You can't do anything with either of these facts, right? You seem to be questioning the entire pursuit of knowledge.

Comment: @mgsam I'm not questioning the pursuit of knowledge, I'm doing the opposite.  I really don't think there's accurate "knowledge" that can be obtained here.  Supposition, guesses, assumptions, sure; but there's no knowledge in that.

Comment: @PeterRitchie ??? I specifically state in my question that I'm looking for reasoning from one of the developers if any such explanation exists.

Comment: The answer is simple ... the designers were incompetent. It makes no logical sense for Add and Remove to be on IList but not on ICollection, and the comments attempting to rationalize it are ridiculous (though not as ridiculous as the rude and offensive anti-intellectualism of PR). It's fortunate that they wised up a little with the generic classes, but the botched ICollection means that you can't write generalized code that operates on non-lists, like HashSet<T> and Dictionary<T>.

Answer (score 4):

To me it seems the naming of the interfaces is confusing the expectations. `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` aren't even in the same inheritance chain - most collections just simply implement both.

The documentation states what the interface does, so taking this alone, one wouldn't expect `Add` to exist:

> Defines size, enumerators, and synchronization methods for all
>   nongeneric collections.

What do I think? Personally I think it's either a straight naming gaff or the second time around (when introducing the generic interfaces) the designers chose to put `Add` in `ICollection<T>` because this time it was more common to need it.

The `IList` has `Add` and inherits `ICollection` whereas the `IList<T>` doesn't have `Add` and inherits `ICollection<T>`, which as `Add`.

Chalk it up to evolution / maturing of the type hierarchy design.

---

As for the extension methods, you can do something like:

```
public static void AnotherMethod<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T item) { }
```

And use it thus:

```
ICollection<string> s;
s.AnotherMethod("");
```

Comment: `ICollection<sting>` ...  I like it, perhaps we can have more decent musical references ;)

Answer (score 1):

`ICollection` can be anything.  It could be something that is nothing but enumerable.  There is no reason there *should* be an `Add` method, or indeed a `Remove`.  If you look at the interface more closely, it's pretty much read-only.  You can see how many elements there are, and you can enumerate them.  That's it.  This makes perfect sense, in an abstract kind of way.

When we get to `ICollection<T>`, we are now being very specific.  We know exactly what kind of object it holds and therefore we can:

- Add new elements of `<T>`.
- Search for them using an `IEquitable` kind of interface.
- Remove them, using the same methodology.

In essence, the difference is that `ICollection<T>` is somewhat concrete.

Comment: I can sort of agree with your take, but I think the underlying reason is more to do with the evolution of the design. `IList` takes add even though you don't know what type is in the list, all non-generic lists have this problem. The second time around with all the new interfaces for generics, the designers can a chance to better unify the base interfaces. Either that or it is just a straight naming gaff.

Answer (score 1):

When `ICollection` was created there was no generic interfaces.  This meant that if there were an `Add` method on `ICollection` it would have to have the signature `Add(object)`.  `ICollection` is meant to declare a consistent interface across collections of any type--which would force each collection to act, partially, like an collection of `object`s.

This has been fixed in `ICollection<T>` which has a method `Add(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Albahari Brothers](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=t1de8nSVYnkC&lpg=PP1&ots=24qgSrPk8A&dq=inauthor%3a%22Ben%20Albahari%22&pg=PA279#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The generic and non-generic versions differ in ways over and above
>   what you might expect,particularly in the case of ICollection.
>
> The reasons for this are mostly historical:**because generics came
>   later**,the generic interfaces were developed with the benefit of
>   **hindsight**.
>
> For this reason,
>
> `ICollection<T>`does not extend `ICollection`,
>
> `IList<T>` does not extend `IList`,
>
> and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not extend `IDictionary`.

To summarize `ICollection<T>` has evolved by not making the mistakes which were made in `ICollection`.This is why `ICollection<T>` has an Add method and `ICollection` not..

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx)

You do not need to add collection types to known types when used polymorphically in place of other collections or collection interfaces. For example, if you declare a data member of type IEnumerable and use it to send an instance of ArrayList, you do not need to add ArrayList to known types.

When you use collections polymorphically in place of non-collection types, they must be added to known types. For example, if you declare a data member of type Object and use it to send an instance of ArrayList, add ArrayList to known types.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Msdn definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.icollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it's

> Defines size, enumerators, and synchronization methods for all
>   nongeneric collections

That means the ICollection rapresents a *stream*  or a *sequence* of data that you gonna read.
Thow I would say that *probabbly* the decision that stands behind the `SharePoint API` is provide *generic stream of data*  you read from the server.

Answer (score 0):

One guess is that if `ICollection` did have the `Add` method, what would it take? `Object` of course. This was a big problem with none generic array, that prior to C# 2.0 had.

The issue would be that you can add different type to the same collection

Comment: This wouldn't really be an issue. You would just have to do a type check in the ICollection.Add(object) method that throws if it's the wrong type.

Comment: @MgSam right, but still feels wrong to have a method that take an object, and then throws an exception.

Comment: MgSam: But how do you define what the right type is if its not generic? And runtime exceptions for things like this don't sound fun to me. Then again, trying to second guess developers sounds like not fun too...

Comment: @MBen `ArrayList` takes `object` so this argument alone isn't enough to discount why `ICollection` doesn't have it, there was once a world before generics.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth ah ok good point. I just checked ICollection was before the world of generics.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess - the ICollection interface is a base interface for other interfaces that extend it, such as IList and IDictionary. Those interfaces have different implementations of the add method. IList takes one param, IDictionary needs two obviously. With generics the derived interface method signatures aren't really different because they takes one param - a type.

Comment: ICollection<T> does not extend ICollection!

Comment: I never said it does. I was speaking about the System.Collections.ICollection interface, which was created prior to generics.